# Windows login and ctrl+alt+delete issue

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, login, login-screen, ctrl-alt-delete

When logging onto a windows 7/8.1 work terminal, pressing control-alt-delete and bringing up the task manager causes the login process to speed up considerably, typically by up to 2 to 5 minutes faster. Does anyone know what mechanism is causing this?

I am interested in why bringing up the TM saves me 2 to 5 minutes of login waiting time. IT dept claim the login is slow due to access provisioning and rights authentication, but no comment on this issue. Does this mean that some part of the process that is causing the long delay is being overriden?

I work in internet security so this something of an anomaly and am curious if anyone has come across the mechanism causing this

Comment: But do you know what the underlying mechanism is that causes ctrl+alt+delete to free a system from a  hangup in general? This is not a hardware specific question as I have experienced this on multiple workstations and home/public computers.

Comment: This is actually a new one for me so I can't really say. Could not replicate on any of my home (non-domain) systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your logs. If you see nothing special, then use Windows Performance Toolkit (`xperf` with `xbootmgr`) to profile your boot/login process.

Comment: It appears my phone app marked this as the accepted answer without my knowledge, sorry.